# Django: want to use loop.counter to assign letter for Google Maps marker

Tags: django, google-maps, django-templates

I've got a variable number of items, somewhere between 0 and 20.

I'd like to list these with Google Static Maps, showing a little "a" for the first one, a "b" for the second one and so on.

I'm a newbie using Google App Engine so I'm constrained to 0.96 (unless I use various patches, which I don't want to do.  Because I'm a newbie.)

```
&markers={% for item in results %}{{item.latitude}},{{item.longitude}}{% if not forloop.last %}|{% endif %}{% endfor %}
```

is working fine to provide a list of red markers.

```
&markers={% for item in results %}{{item.latitude}},{{item.longitude}},{{forloop.counter0}}{% if not forloop.last %}|{% endif %}{% endfor %}
```

gets me 0-9 on the map.

For now, I've cut the result set down to 10.  I'd like to go back to 20.  Is there a way of using the loopcounter and slice (as in {{ alpha_list|slice:":loop_counter"}} ?  I struggled with various incantations, trying {{ }} around loop_counter and without and couldn't get it to work.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want do it entirely within the template, you can use the [cycle tag](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/?from=olddocs#cycle).

Something like the following, with ... expanded:

```
{% cycle 'a' 'b' ... 'z' as alphabet %}
&markers={% for item in results %}{{item.latitude}},{{item.longitude}},{% cycle alphabet %}{% if not forloop.last %}|{% endif %}{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 2):

Easiest would be to write a template tag.  There's a [good tut](http://codespatter.com/2009/01/22/how-to-write-django-template-tags/), but the code would basically be:

```
def inttoalpha(n):
    a = ord('A')
    return chr(a+n)
```

Comment: Thanks for the lead.   Implementing tags looks like something I will circle back to later.  I'll stick with 10 items for now.

Answer (score 0):

create a template tag using method provided here

[How do I iterate through a string in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/228730/how-do-i-iterate-through-the-alphabet-in-python)