# How to make a list of characters in Python

Tags: python, list, character

My exam question asks me to take two letters as inputs, and display all letters in the alphabet between the two inputs (inclusively). It also needs to do this in the order the user input them (so GA produces `GFEDCBA` not `ABCDEFG`). How would I approach this task?

Comment: `comments like "learn to do it yourself" are not helpful.` Yeah, I guess you're right. If you're in the middle of an exam there isn't much time left to learn anything.

Comment: [How do I iterate through the alphabet in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/228730/1622937) might help you - but try to clarify such questions before the exam...

Comment: One liner...
print "%s" % list((chr(i) for i in range(ord(begin), ord(end) + 1 * (ord(end)-ord(begin))/abs(ord(end)-ord(begin)), (ord(end)-ord(begin))/abs(ord(end)-ord(begin)))))

Comment: Oh, sorry, I seem to have caused some confusion... I'm not in an exam, it's just a practice exam paper as some homework :)

Comment: Trying to gag people before they could talk is not a good way of asking a question. -1 just for that.

Comment: @BorrajaX: Please don't put so much code in a comment -- post an answer.

Comment: @martineau Um.. did you actually read the original question? By the way, it's a metaphor. I didn't mean literal gagging. Jeez, man.

Comment: @JamesJiao: Yes I saw the original -- simply didn't know whether you meant the OP, people making comments, or what. Still don't really understand exactly what bothered you.

Comment: @martineau *Please help me, BUT don't say this, that and that.* That's what bothered me. If I wanted help, I wouldn't just start by assuming that I will get unconstructive responses. That's what rules and FAQs are for.

Comment: @JamesJiao I wasn't assuming I will get unconstructive responses, I was merely saving those who would put 'unconstructive' responses the effort of doing so. Telling someone to learn it themselves can actually be constructive, by the way.

Answer (score 2):

I didn't really think this would be worth an answer, but as @martineau said in [his comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13692070/how-to-make-a-list-of-characters-in-python#comment18802418_13692070), it's not a good idea to put so much code in a comment... so here it goes:

```
>>> begin="A"
>>> end="G"
>>> print "%s" % list((chr(i) for i in range(ord(begin), ord(end) + 1 * (ord(end)-ord(begin))/abs(ord(end)-ord(begin)), (ord(end)-ord(begin))/abs(ord(end)-ord(begin))))) 
['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G']
>>> begin="G"
>>> end="A"
>>> print "%s" % list((chr(i) for i in range(ord(begin), ord(end) + 1 * (ord(end)-ord(begin))/abs(ord(end)-ord(begin)), (ord(end)-ord(begin))/abs(ord(end)-ord(begin))))) 
['G', 'F', 'E', 'D', 'C', 'B', 'A']
```

The only slightly relevant parts are [chr](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#chr) and [ord](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#ord), and the "trick" of `(ord(end)-ord(begin))/abs(ord(end)-ord(begin))` to get -1 if *begin > end*, though...

**Edit**: As @martineau pointed out in [another comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13692070/how-to-make-a-list-of-characters-in-python#comment18802652_13692070)... you can make an even bigger(!) one liner and get an string (instead of a list) by using [join](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.join).

```
>>> begin="G"
>>> end="A"
>>> print "".join((chr(i) for i in range(ord(begin), ord(end) + 1 * (ord(end)-ord(begin))/abs(ord(end)-ord(begin)), (ord(end)-ord(begin))/abs(ord(end)-ord(begin)))))
GFEDCBA
```

... which is a trivial chunk of code ... **:D**

Comment: If you change the `list(...)` to `''.join(...)` the result will be a string like `ABCDEFG`.

Comment: You don't need the `list(` in the `"".join(list((chr(...`.

Comment: @martineau: That's right... Edited :)

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> import string
>>> def letterList (start, end):
        # add a character at the beginning so str.index won't return 0 for `A`
        a = ' ' + string.ascii_uppercase

        # if start > end, then start from the back
        direction = 1 if start < end else -1

        # Get the substring of the alphabet:
        # The `+ direction` makes sure that the end character is inclusive; we
        # always need to go one *further*, so when starting from the back, we
        # need to substract one. Here comes also the effect from the modified
        # alphabet. For `A` the normal alphabet would return `0` so we would
        # have `-1` making the range fail. So we add a blank character to make
        # sure that `A` yields `1-1=0` instead. As we use the indexes dynamically
        # it does not matter that we have changed the alphabet before.
        return a[a.index(start):a.index(end) + direction:direction]

>>> letterList('A', 'G')
'ABCDEFG'
>>> letterList('G', 'A')
'GFEDCBA'
>>> letterList('A', 'A')
'A'
```

Note that this solution allows any kind of alphabet. We could set `a = ' ' + string.ascii_uppercase + string.ascii_lowercase` and get such results:

```
>>> letterList('m', 'N')
'mlkjihgfedcbaZYXWVUTSRQPON'
```

And who needs ASCII when you have full unicode support?

```
>>> a = ' あいうえおかきくけこさしすせそたちつてとなにぬねのはひふへほまみむめもやゆよらりるれろわを'
>>> letterList('し', 'ろ')
'しすせそたちつてとなにぬねのはひふへほまみむめもやゆよらりるれろ'
```

Comment: Seems like true "full unicode support" would mean not having to predefine the alphabet to be used beforehand...

Comment: @martineau If you want to use Unicode’s ordering and accept that there are many code points are empty, sure.

Comment: Yes, I know. I wrote one but the question was closed when I was ready to submit it. Probably way more than the OP was interested in anyway.